# Set UIView height depending on screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, screen, screen-size

I've a UIView under a table.
I've got to set UIView height for iPhone 4S or 5.
I tried using

```
- (void) regolaViewPeriPhone {
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(result.height == 480)
        {
            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 210, 320, 245);
            _pickerContainerView.frame = frame;
        }
        if(result.height == 568)
        {
            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 210, 320, 290);
            _pickerContainerView.frame = frame;
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work, what's right method? Thank you!

Comment: Is regolaViewPeriPhone being called?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the way to "Set UIView height depending on screen size"

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
{
  //Do u r stuff here for Iphone 5
}
else if(screenBounds.size.height==480)
{
  //Do u r stuff here for Iphone 4s
}
```

//if my answer is correct then vote up for me...

Comment: No. Do not do this. Never use hard coded values in your code. If the screen size ever changes you will have problems.  Also, I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: Pandu' s suggestion works! Do you suggest to use "applicationFrame" instead "bounds"?

Comment: If you need the size for your app, use applicationFrame. This is the correct frame. It also reflects whether there is a hidden status bar or a double-height status bar (during a phone call or when using tethering). Your should try to figure out what's wrong in your NIB that is keeping your view from being resized properly automatically. Then write layout code that works based on whatever the view size is.

Comment: If you hit minus please provide your own correct answer. Otherwise we know what not to do but we don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

`[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] applicationFrame ]`

Comment: but really, your containing view controller should handle this for you. check your autoresizing flags in IB...

Comment: So there's an enclosing scroll view?

Comment: You sure your view is behind the table not inside it?